# In SQL Server, how do I create a function that returns a text longer than 8,000 characters?

Tags: sql-server, function, text, varchar, sqldatatypes

I need to create a function in SQL Server that returns a string. In some cases, this string is longer than 8,000 characters, which is the maximum value for a varchar data type. text, and ntext data types are not supported when writing functions in SQL Server 2008.

So any idea of an alternative that I could implement ?

Thank You

(The code used for creating the function is very long, so I didn't included it)

Comment: Text1 varchar(max), Text2 vachar(max)  select Text1 + Text2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a `VARCHAR(MAX)` as the return type of the function.

Answer (score -1):

You can return two strings. Or you can return a blob.

Comment: Not possible for the purposes that I intend to use the function, but thank you I already found an answer